# Generate multiple random DNA sequences in a file with no more than 3 repeated letters in a row

Tags: python

I have an assignment where I am supposed to generate random dna sequences in a file, I got it to generate one randomly, but I am having trouble generating more than one. I also have to add a piece of code that prohibits the random generation from having more than 3 repeating letters in a row, I am not sure how to do that. This is what I have so far:

```
import random

def dna(length, sequences):
    f = open("dna.txt", 'w')
    dna = ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
    random_sequence = " "
    for i in range(length):
        random_sequence+=random.choice(dna)
    list = []
    i = 0
    while i < sequences:
        x = random_sequence
        list.append(x)
        i = i+i
    f.write(random_sequence)
    f.close()


print(dna(15, 20))
```

Comment: How would you want to differentiate the different DNA sequences in the file? You do want only one file, right? Also, how would you ensure there aren't more than 3 repeated characters if you were doing this on paper? Could you take that logic and translate that into code?

Comment: Tackle this problem piece by piece. Cut big problems into smaller subproblems and start writing small functions that handle the smaller subproblems. If a subproblem seems overwhelming, cut that subproblem up aswell.  That way, you can piece a solution together without overwhelming yourself. Divide and conquer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
import random

# Create a single sequence
def dna_seq(length, max_repeat=3):
    dna = ["A", "T", "C", "G"]
    seq = []
    while len(seq) < length:
        d = random.choice(dna)
        # Make sure no repeats > max_repeat
        if seq[-max_repeat:] != [d] * max_repeat:
            seq.append(d)
    return ''.join(seq)

# Create all the sequences and save
def dna(length, sequences):
  with open("dna.txt", 'w') as f:
      for _ in range(sequences):
          f.write(dna_seq(length) + '\n')

dna(15, 20)
```